# Object detection in image after training data

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, object-detection

Good day to all, i have question about i get the code of training the surface crack detection the do test and show the confidence level of crack in table form. After that, i want to show it in like object detection of crack in image form with showing bounding box and confidence level at the top of the box. How to write the code?
Below is showing the coding of the testing and some result of the image data

[image]

```
def test_new_data(dir_path):

    new_test_dir = Path(dir_path)

    df_new = generate_df(new_test_dir, 'Testing')

    test_data_new = test_gen.flow_from_dataframe(df_new,
                                          x_col='Filepath',
                                          y_col='Label',
                                          target_size=(120,120),
                                          color_mode='rgb',
                                          batch_size=5,
                                          shuffle=False,
                                          seed=42)

        # predicted y values
    y_pred = np.squeeze((model.predict(test_data_new) >= 0.5).astype(np.int))


    y_certain = model.predict(test_data_new).round(6)
    y_out = []
    for i in y_pred:
        if i==0:
            y_out.append('Negative (Not Crack)')
        else:
            y_out.append('Positive(Crack) ')

    result = pd.DataFrame(np.c_[y_out, y_certain], columns=['Result', 'Confidance of being Cracked'])

    return result
result =  test_new_data(r'/content/drive/MyDrive/surface crack detection/test')
```